# Como atribuir uma fonte Json dento de uma interface

Tags: json, angular, interface

> Estou tentando gerar uma interface de um arquivo Json mas esta
>   dando erro, qual seria o erro do no meu código?

```
 export interface Compra {
        event: string;
        timestamp: number;
        custom_data: number;
        value: string;
        key: number;
    }




{"events":[{"event":"comprou-produto",
                "timestamp":"2017-09-22T13:52:24.2311892-30:00",
                "custom_data":[{"key":"product_name",
                                "value":"Pants"},
                        {"key":"transaction_id","value":"135154"},
                               {"key":"product_price","value":131}]},

               {"event":"comprou",
                "timestamp":"2016-09-22T13:57:31.2311892-03:00",
                "revenue":250,
                "custom_data":[{"key":"store_name","value":"Loja y"},{"key":"transaction_id","value":"3029384"}]},

               {"event":"comprou-produto","timestamp":"2016-09-22T13:57:33.2311892-03:00","custom_data":[{"key":"product_price","value":150},{"key":"transaction_id","value":"3216545"},{"key":"product_name","value":"Shirt"}]},

               {"event":"comprou-produto","timestamp":"2016-10-02T11:37:35.2300892-03:00","custom_data":[{"key":"transaction_id","value":"3409340"},{"key":"product_name","value":"Shoes"},{"key":"product_price","value":120}]},

               {"event":"comprou","timestamp":"2016-10-02T11:37:31.2300892-03:00","revenue":120,"custom_data":[{"key":"transaction_id","value":"32132131"},{"key":"store_name","value":"Loja x"}]}]}`insira o código aqui`
```

Comment: Qual erro que está dando? 
* Detalhe que notei, seu atributo custom_data está como number, mas na verdade é um objeto *

Comment: estou tentando fazer essa estrutura html:

Comment: <span class="content-date">{{compra.timestamp}}</span>
        <h3 class="content-sumprice">{{compra.custom_data}}</h3>
        <h3 class="content-store">{{compra.value}}</h3>

Comment: <div *ngFor="let compra of events">
            <tl-compra [compra]="compra"></tl-compra>
            </div>

Comment: Ta dando esse erro: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa declara duas interfaces e usar uma dentro da outra:

```
export interface Compra {
        event: string;
        timestamp: number;
        custom_data: CustomData[];
    }


export interface CustomData{
        value: string;
        key: number;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, valeu pela dica, a minha saida no html esta assim como devo deveriar representar o CustomData:                                                                                               <span class="content-date">{{compra.timestamp.key}}</span>
        <h3 class="content-store">{{compra.value}}</h3>
        <!--<h3 class="content-sumprice">{{compra.custom_data}}</h3>