# Como consumir um dado Json vindo um endereço http

Tags: json, angular, http

> Estou tentando consumir um dado Json vindo de um endereço http, mas
>   não sei o que esta dando errado.
>
> eu dividi a pergunta em dois grupos [minha outra duvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328805/como-atribuir-uma-fonte-json-dento-de-uma-interface?noredirect=1#comment666001_328805)

```
   import { ComprasService } from './compras.service';

import { Compra } from './../compra/compra.model';

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'tl-compras',
  templateUrl: './compras.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compras.component.css']
})
export class ComprasComponent implements OnInit {


events: Compra[];

  constructor(private comprasService: ComprasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.comprasService.events().subscribe(events => this.events = events);
  }
}
```

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { PRODUC_API } from '../app.api';
    import {Http} from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';
    import { Compra } from '../compra/compra.model';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


    @Injectable()
    export class ComprasService {

        constructor(private http: Http) {}

        events(): Observable<Compra[]> {
            return this.http.get('${PRODUC_API}/events').map(response => response.json());
        }

    }
```

Comment: então Utilizei no Ionic uma vez segue link Criado um proxy para conexão
https://github.com/leandroZanatta/mobWashMobile/blob/master/src/providers/proxy/proxy.ts utilizando o proxy
https://github.com/leandroZanatta/mobWashMobile/blob/master/src/pages/cadastro/cadastro.ts Talvez Ajude

Comment: Da algum erro? Aparece alguma coisa no console? COmo esta seu html?

Comment: Veja na taba netowrk do devTools se a request esta retornando o que vc espera.

Comment: Qual versão do angular você esta usando?

Comment: Boa tarde, utilize a ferramento do navegador para verificar se possui algum erro no console. Pode utilizar essa ferramenta aperta F12 do navegador ... Se tiver algum erro, cole aqui para podermos dar uma olhada.

Comment: O erro que aparece e esse:                                                                                                               :4200/$%7BPRODUC_API%7D/events:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: core.js:1673 ERROR Responseheaders: Headers {_headers: Map(8), _normalizedNames: Map(8)}ok: falsestatus: 404statusText: "Not Found"type: 2url: "http://localhost:4200/$%7BPRODUC_API%7D/events"_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot GET /$%7BPRODUC_API%7D/events</pre>↵</body>↵</html>↵"__proto__: Body
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673